# Display text line one after another with delay

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

In my HTML page, we need to display text line one after another with delay. But condition is when second line displays, first line should change the color. Then when third line displays, second line should change the color.

I have used jquery.fadeInAmate.js and in that we can achieve displaying the text lines one after another in certain delays. But for color change is not happening in that.

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#slideShow").show();
    $(".fadeInAmate").fadeInAmate({
      initialDelay: 250,
      fadeInSpeed: 2000,
      animationDelay: 5000
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jforaker.github.io/jQuery-FadeInAmate/src/jquery.fadeInAmate.js"></script>
<div id="slideShow">
  <p class="fadeInAmate">This is my first line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Here goes my second line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Then comes third line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Following to that fourth line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">And finally here goes my fifth line</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Where are you trying to change the color?

Comment: It doesn't look like the plugin you're using exposes any events ([source](https://github.com/jforaker/jQuery-FadeInAmate/blob/master/src/jquery.fadeInAmate.js)), so you can't easily know when an element started fading in in order to change the colour of previous ones. I'd suggest writing your own logic, or using a different library

Comment: It has been written in different script. You can see that in "jquery.fadeInAmate.js"

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the plugin you're using exposes any events ([source](https://github.com/jforaker/jQuery-FadeInAmate/blob/master/src/jquery.fadeInAmate.js)), so you can't easily know when an element started fading in in order to change the colour of previous ones. I'd suggest using a different library, or writing your own logic, like this:

```js
$("#slideShow .fadeInAmate").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(3000 * i).fadeIn(2000, function() {
    $(this).prev().addClass('foo');
  });
});
```

```css
#slideShow p {
  display: none;
}

.foo {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jforaker.github.io/jQuery-FadeInAmate/src/jquery.fadeInAmate.js"></script>
<div id="slideShow">
  <p class="fadeInAmate">This is my first line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Here goes my second line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Then comes third line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">Following to that fourth line</p>
  <p class="fadeInAmate">And finally here goes my fifth line</p>
</div>
```